# weekend weekdays string date formatting

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

says you have this array `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`, `0` represent sunday, `1` represent monday... till the `6` represent saturday.

I want to produce string output like below:

```
weekdays //[1,2,3,4,5]
weekends //[0,6]
mon, tue, wed //[1,2,3]
```

it can also be mixed group like,

```
weekends, thu //[0,6,4]
weekdays, sat //[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

*The comment is input, and the output is on the left.

Tried moment but couldn't find any method to parse it.

Comment: Please add input and expected output.

Comment: @Justcode the array is input, the string at the left is output.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
function getHumanDescription(daysArray) {
        const dayNames = [ 'sat', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sun' ]
        const weekdays = [1,2,3,4,5]
        const weekend = [0,6]
        let description = []
        if(weekdays.every(day => daysArray.includes(day))) {
            description.push('weekdays')
            daysArray = daysArray.filter(day => !weekdays.includes(day))
        }
        if(weekend.every(day => daysArray.includes(day))) {
            description.push('weekends');
            daysArray = daysArray.filter(day => !weekend.includes(day))
        }
        daysArray.forEach(day => description.push(dayNames[day]))
        return description.join(', ')
    }
    
    console.log(getHumanDescription([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]));
    console.log(getHumanDescription([0,5,6]));
    console.log(getHumanDescription([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
    console.log(getHumanDescription([1,3,4,5,6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take at it. Hope it helps.

```js
const week = {
  SUNDAY: 0,
  MONDAY: 1,
  TUESDAY: 2,
  WEDNESDAY: 3,
  THURSDAY: 4,
  FRIDAY: 5,
  SATURDAY: 6,
  weekday: [1,2,3,4,5],
  weekend: [0,6]
};

let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]; //weekdays
let array2 = [0,6]; //weekends
let array3 = [1,2,3]; //mon, tue, wed
let array4 = [0,6,4]; //weekends, thu
let array5 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; //weekdays, sat

let keys = Object.keys(week);
let values = Object.values(week);

function parseArray(array) {
  let isWeekend = week.weekend.every((val) => array.includes(val));
  let isWeek = week.weekday.every((val) => array.includes(val));
  let foundDays = [];
  //console.log("Contains Weekend: " + isWeekend);
  //console.log("Contains Week: " + isWeek);
  
  isWeekend ? foundDays.push("Weekend") : null;
  isWeek ? foundDays.push("Weekdays") : null;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let foundIndex = values.indexOf(array[i]);
    if (isWeek && foundIndex > 0 && foundIndex < 6) {
      continue;
    }
    
    if (isWeekend && (foundIndex === 0 || foundIndex === 6)) {
      continue;
    }
    
    if (foundIndex > -1) {
        foundDays.push(keys[foundIndex]);
    }
  }
  
  console.log(foundDays);
}

parseArray(array1);
parseArray(array2);
parseArray(array3);
parseArray(array4);
parseArray(array5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with moment. I would create a function to do this for you.
Something like below.

```js
function getDays(input) {
  const ref = {
    weekdays: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    weekends: [0, 6],
    sun: [0],
    mon: [1],
    tue: [2],
    wed: [3],
    thu: [4],
    fri: [5],
    sat: [6]
  }

  let output = []; //this will hold array of output days

  //Check for each combination in ref object
  for (prop in ref) {
    let isPresent = ref[prop].every(item => {
      return input.indexOf(item) !== -1;
    });

    //if the combination is present add to output and remove those days from input
    if (isPresent) {
      output.push(prop);
      input = input.reduce((acc, value) => {
        if (ref[prop].indexOf(value) !== -1) {
          return acc;
        } else {
          acc.push(value);
          return acc;
        }
      }, []);
    }
  }

  return output.join(', ');
}

console.log(getDays([1, 2]));
console.log(getDays([0, 3, 6]));
console.log(getDays([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach:-

```
var daysOfWeek = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,[0,6],[1,2,3,4,5]];
var dayNames = ['sun','mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'weekends','weekdays' ];

function mapDescriptionWithDays(inpString){
inpArray=inpString.split(',');

var output='';
for(i=0; i< inpArray.length ; i++){
        output += ','+daysOfWeek[dayNames.indexOf((inpArray[i]).trim())];
}
  output=output.substring(1);
  output='[' + output +']';
  return output;
}
var a = mapDescriptionWithDays('weekdays, sat');
alert(a);
```

Comment: The string representation is the output and array of day numbers should be the input.